# How can I force delete my own question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

There are a lot of question similar to it but I want to give a good reason to do this.

I did this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64616/how-to-build-the-circuit-of-a-small-wireless-camera

The answer was not exactly good, but the problem is the information that I put in it. Maybe, I will sell the project and if the people that will buy it search my name and find it, I can have a problem and lost money. Even if he search it without my name, I will have the same problem.

Maybe I don't sell anything, but now this information have a good value to me. :) So, how can I force to delete it because I don't want to show this information anymore!

It was online for 4 month, so I thing this time pay the answer. Maybe I accept to restore it in one year.

So how can I force to delete my own question?

Ps. I flag the question but it not solve the problem!

Comment: [Streisand effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) here we come...

Comment: Lol... Yes this can cause more problem than solve it.... If it is not possible, lol, delete THIS question :)

Comment: It's not possible. You can go ahead and delete this question yourself if you want. But if it gets upvoted answers you won't be able to delete this one either.

Comment: Just forget about it. The best thing to do with Streisand effect is not say anymore from what you want to hidden :D  Even if I try to delete THIS question, I will not learn about it :)

Comment: You can always get 10k rep and use your semi-moderator powers to delete it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't.

It looks to be a reasonable question, fairly popular, with answers.  The question isn't yours to delete (see the Stack Exchange [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) paragraph 3, Subscriber Content)

The most you could probably do is delete your account if you're concerned that your name might be associated with it.

Personally, I'd do the opposite.  Be proud that you asked a good question.

Comment: Also, btw; Rodrigo could request the question be disassociated from his account.

Comment: OK. When I read about Streisand effect I thought better. Maybe this will not cause any problem is just my head thinking bad things...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Dan's answer, users with 10k rep have access to select moderator privileges. One of them is the ability to delete questions. So, if you get 10k rep on the site, you can delete your question.

However, if you have access to these tools, you are expected to use them *properly*. Deleting your own questions, especially if they are good questions (as @Dan mentioned), you can gain the watch of the actual moderators, and you **do not** want to upset the overlords.

Comment: A more likely consequence than upsetting moderators would be that (1) other 10k users wouldn't contribute the necessary delete votes to cause deletion (being 10k doesn't confer insta-delete powers), or (2) if somehow it did get deleted, it would get undeleted pretty quickly. If both of those failed, *then* the negative attention of moderators (and perhaps the community at large) would be incurred. :)

Comment: Our wrath is sparkly!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, you should learn that there is a regular [Data Dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump) made available and archived *forever*, so deletion will not work. One thing you always need to keep in mind on the internet is that **there is no un-post**. Once published, it's impossible to be certain all copies are eliminated.

Comment: The data dump is a sanitized database copy. i.e. deleted posts are hidden. The only things available are what someone logged out would be able to see.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Not exactly. If you grab a pre-deletion dump (if it exists, as it almost certainly is the case for such an old post) it won't magically catch up. There's even http://stackprinter.com to browse deleted posts